# WAGMI useContractWrite() hook unresponsive/not working

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, react, wagmi

I've been trying to write to a contract on a local blockchain (Anvil from Foundry) but running the `write()` function (running it after submitting a form `write?.()`) does not work.

Tried to disable the submit button in the form by `disabled={!write}` and waited for a few minutes, it still does not work. Double checked the ABI and Token Address too, they seem to be correct.

here's the code for the page

```js
function TokenForm() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        tokenName: '',
        tokenSymbol: '',
        initialMintAmount: '',
    })

    const debouncedFormData = useDebounce(formData, 500)

    const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        address: tokenFactoryAddress,
        contractInterface: abi,
        functionName: 'createToken',
        args: [
            debouncedFormData.tokenName,
            debouncedFormData.tokenSymbol,
            (
                BigInt(debouncedFormData.initialMintAmount) * BigInt(10 ** 18)
            ).toString(),
        ],
    })

    const { isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite(config)

    function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target
        setFormData((prevFormData) => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: value,
            }
        })
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        write?.()
        console.log(isSuccess)
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={styles.form}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="your token's name"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="tokenName"
                    value={formData.tokenName}
                    className={styles.inputBox}
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="your token's symbol"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="tokenSymbol"
                    value={formData.tokenSymbol}
                    className={styles.inputBox}
                />

                <input
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="initial tokens to mint"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="initialMintAmount"
                    value={formData.initialMintAmount}
                    className={styles.inputBox}
                />
                {/* disabled={!write} */}
                <button disabled={!write}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For more context the function `createToken()` takes in 3 arguments - a string `name`, another string `symbol` and a uint256 `initialMintAmount`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In `usePrepareContractWrite()` I have written `contractInterface: abi` it should be `abi: abi`